# Java - How can these 2 objects equal each other?

Tags: java, object, reference

Hi I am revising and understand the difference between equals() and '==' however this code really confuses me:

```
public class MyTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer w = new Integer(1);
        Integer x = 1;
        double z = x;
        System.out.println(z == w);
    }
}
```

How can a double object have the same reference as an Integer object in memory when using '==' ? Cannot understand this. Thank you for reading!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you compare primitive and wrapper using `==` operator, then the wrapper values will be un boxed and compared with primitive value.

From [JLS 15.21.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21.1)

> **15.21.1. Numerical Equality Operators == and !=**
>
> If the operands of an equality operator are both of numeric type, or
>   one is of numeric type and the other is convertible ([§5.1.8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.8)) to
>   numeric type, binary numeric promotion is performed on the operands
>   ([§5.6.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2)).

Comment: Thank you, I had a tricky question like this in the preparation for my exam.

Comment: it's not true what u r writing Abimaran.

Comment: @MironBalcerzak, Then what's correct? Can you link to JLS?

Comment: @Abimaran, check Integer.IntegerCache. I will look for JLS and link in couple of moments - once I find it... "adjustments" like that are not on the 1st page of java doc. ;-/

Comment: @MironBalcerzak It has nothing to do with Integer caching (by the way w is not cached, it is a whole new integer).

Comment: @MironBalcerzak To expand on assylias' answer, `Integer` caching only comes into effect if you use the `Integer#valueOf()` method, if memory serves

Comment: Thank you all very much, I understand perfectly now. Will make sure to remember this for my exam :)

Answer (score 0):

A `double` is not a reference, because it is a primitive type. It is a value instead. `Double` would have been a reference.

When you write `z == w`, where `z` is `double`-typed and `w` is `Integer`-typed, the runtime definitely has to compare something. And, obviously, it has to compare things of the same kind. It will not compare the `double` value with the `Integer` reference. Instead, it will unbox the `Integer` and will compare the `int` value obtained after unboxing with the `double` value. Both being 1, the boolean operator will return `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Here objects are not compared but `primitive` types are compared with `feature` of unboxing for `Integer`.